# How to spot-fill low spots in concrete self leveler for shower pan?

Tags: concrete, subfloor, self-leveling-concrete

I am attempting a shower renovation. I poured self leveler in the shower area to smooth out the surface for installation of a Schluter foam pan. I ended up with some low areas, and I'm looking for some help on how to fill those without repouring a new concrete layer. Can these be filled with extra thinset when installing the pan, or is there a flooring compound that can do the trick? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How did you end up with low spots with a "self leveling compound"?

Comment: Don't shower pans require a preslope to direct shower water toward the drain at a grade? If you're planning this step, why even self-level as a preliminary step?

Comment: Henry makes a product called FeatherFinish. Henry 549. That's what I probably would use, but you didn't spec how out of flat your surface is.